# How to return a result set from oracle procedure ?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, stored-procedures, select

How can i return a result set from a stored procedure in oracle ?
suppose i want to return a table from a simple select statement such as this :

```
Select * from tblTest
```

I tried this but this seems plain wrong!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE ProcSelectEveryThing(cursor_ OUT TYPES.REF_CURSOR)
AS

BEGIN

OPEN cursor_ FOR
      SELECT * FROM "tblTest"; 
END;
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a return statement, because it is using OPEN and FOR... It is the same like RETURN...

The error is in the name of the table, you put it in "" double quotes.  Remove that, use simply the name of the table, and use the type  SYS_REFCURSOR like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE ProcSelectEveryThing(cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS

BEGIN

OPEN cursor_ FOR
      SELECT * FROM tblTest; 
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a RETURN statement in your PL/SQL. Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101033/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-the-stored-procedure-oracle-pl-sql). There are any number of sites which can provide a quick response to this query. I recommend that you download SQLDeveloper and look at some of the system supplied stuff and check out the docco, starting [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm). [SQLDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) is really great - and it's free!